# How to externalize the decorator in python flask application

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, python-decorators, externalizing

I have written a python Flask application, which has a class and methods as below.

```py
class PythonSample:
    def method1():
        pass # does something

    def method2():
        pass # does something
```

Now I have written another class which has decorator functions as below.

```py
class PythonAuth:
    def oauthAuth():
        pass
```

Now I'm wiring oauthAuth decorator for all the methods of PythonSample class as below

```py
import oauthAuth from PythonAuth

class PythonSample
    @oauthAuth
    def method1():
        pass # does something

    @oauthAuth
    def method2():
        pass # does something
```

Applying decorator at each method works fine.

Question: Instead of applying oauthAuth decorator to each of the methods. Is there a way to configure in python, as apply oauthAuth decorator to all the methods in a class and exclude certain methods.

Something like include auth for certain URLs and exclude authentication for certain urls

Please ignore the syntax of the python code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class decorator plus some magic.

## Decorating Functions

Assume you have a decorator that just logs a string before calling the function.

```py
def log(func):
    def logged_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print('logged')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
    return logged_func
```

## Decorating classes

You can use the same trick, but with a class. `log_all` is a class decorator, `cls` is a class type. We use `vars` to walk the class dictionary, and look for methods by using `callable(v)`. Decorate the method with `log(v)` and use `setattr` to change the `cls` definition to the new decorated method. Just like function decorators, return the class in the end.

```py
def log_all(cls):
    for k, v in vars(cls).items():
            if callable(v):
                    setattr(cls, k, log(v))
    return cls
```

*I am ignoring `k` essentially, but `k` is the method name, you could leverage it to achieve your usage scenario.*

## Full code

Here is a full example, that should make some sense now.

```py
def log(func):
    def logged_func(*args, **kwargs):
            print('logged')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
    return logged_func

def log_all(cls):
    for k, v in vars(cls).items():
            if callable(v):
                    setattr(cls, k, log(v))
    return cls

@log_all
class A:
    def method(self):
            pass
```

Every method in class `A` should be decorated with the `log` decorator.

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> a.method()
logged
```